# JavaScript keypress flechas

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

cuando presiono "A" + "B" si se ejecuta, pero cuando presiono "Tecla derecha" + "Tecla izquierda" no, tampoco con las demás flechas, solo con letras, este es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
 const simultaneo=new Map()
 document.addEventListener("keydown", event => simultaneo.set(event.code))
 document.addEventListener("keyup", event => simultaneo.delete(event.code))

 document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
    
 if(simultaneo.has("ArrowRight") && simultaneo.has("ArrowLeft")){
    console.log("x")
 }else if(simultaneo.has("KeyA") && simultaneo.has("KeyB")){
    console.log("y")
 }})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las arrowsKeys se disparan siempre con el evento 'onkeydown', el evento 'onkeypress' no siempre funciona con las flechas y depende del navegador, usa 'onkeydown' con una función flecha o funcion normal y te funcionara.

```
document.onkeydown = event => {
  if(simultaneo.has("ArrowRight") && simultaneo.has("ArrowLeft"))  console.log("x")
}
```